# setting the missing values of dictionary with default value python

Tags: python

I have one defaultdict(list) and other normal dictionary

```
A = {1:["blah", "nire"], 2:["fooblah"], 3:["blahblah"]}
B = {1: "something" ,2:"somethingsomething"}
```

now lets say that i have something like this

```
missing_value = "fill_this"
```

Now, first I want to find what are the keys in B missing from A (like 3 is missing)
and then set those keys to the values `missing_value`?
What is the pythonic way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
for k in A:
    B.setdefault(k, "fill_this")
```

This is essentially the same as the longer:

```
for k in A:
    if k not in B:
        B[k] = "fill_this"
```

However, since `setdefault` only needs to lookup each `k` once, `setdefault` is faster than this "test&set" solution.

Alternatively (and probably slower), determine the set difference and set (no pun intended) those values:

```
for k in set(A).difference(B):
    B[k] = "fill_this"
```

Comment: hi.. what if A is a defaultdict(list) (sorry missed this in original description.. mybad)

Comment: Then it works just as well. `defaultdict` implements its own `setdefault`.

Comment: I think it sould be `if k not in B`.

Comment: `B.setdefault` could even be put out of the loop in some name e.x. `B_set_def` to avoid methods lookups on B.

Comment: Caching `B.setdefault` is probably [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization). It's [explicitly mentioned in Dubious Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DubiousPython#Premature_Optimization).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to go through `A` and update `B` where necessary. It would have `O(len(A))` complexity:

```
for key in A:
    if key not in B:
        B[key] = missing_value
```

Comment: hi.. what if A is a defaultdict(list) (sorry missed this in original description.. mybad)

Comment: @phihag You are right about the needless creating of `set` in memory. I've already updated the answer to reflect that. `set(A)-set(b)` is `O(len(A))` complexity because the algorithm goes through `set(A)` and looks for each element of `set(A)` if it's in `set(B)` which is `O(1)` for each element. But eventually you are right :) Because before the sets are subtracted, `set(B)` is created which is `O(len(B))`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
def test():
    A = {1:"blah", 2:"fooblah", 3:"blahblah"}
    B = {1: "something" ,2:"somethingsomething"}
    keys=set(A.keys()).difference(set(B.keys()))
    for k in keys:
        B[k]="missing"
    print (B)
```

Answer (score -1):

When I've seen a need for this, there were a standard set of keys to be checked in a dict of dicts. If that's the case and if performance is not a significant factor, I think this is the cleanest syntax.

```
template = {k: default for k in domain}
for k, d in dicts.items():
    dicts[k] = template.copy().update(d)
```

Comment: This is actually wrong, of course, because update() doesn't return the updated dict. Fixing it makes it a bit less concise, but still a useful pattern.