# Setting default value in Python dictionary if key is missing

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Given a dictionary I need to check if certain keys exists, if they do I need to get their value, if they don't, then I have to set a default value. I am currently using this code:

```
if 'key1' in my_dict:
    pass
else:
    my_dict['key1'] = 'Not Available'

if 'key2' in my_dict:
    pass
else:
    my_dict['key2'] = 'Not Available'

if 'key3' in my_dict:
    pass
else:
    my_dict['key3'] = 'Not Available'

if 'key4' in my_dict:
    pass
else:
    my_dict['key4'] = 'Not Available'
```

This is of course painful, I guess I could iterate over the entire dictionary keys and check if the keys of interest are present, and if not, then set them. So the question is, is there a better way to do this? By this I mean, go through a large dictionary, check for keys, if they are not present set them to 'Not Available'.

Comment: Consider `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: Well, for starters, here you should use `if key not in my_dict: my_dict[key] = "not available` instead of checking the opposite and `pass`ing

Comment: But there are *various* ways to handle default values in `dict` objects, the easiest being using `my_dict.get(key, default_value)` when you want to retreive the value of a key that may not be there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting the missing values of dictionary with default value python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811475/setting-the-missing-values-of-dictionary-with-default-value-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method

```
my_dict = {"a":1,"b":2}
```

If a key exists, there is no change made to the existing value

```
my_dict.setdefault('a', 3)
print(my_dict) #{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

If it doesn't exist, the key-value pair is added

```
my_dict.setdefault('c', 3)
print(my_dict) #{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Looping through multiple keys :

```
my_dict = {"a":1,"b":2}
keys = ["a","c","d"]
for key in keys:
    my_dict.setdefault(key, "Not Available")

print(my_dict) #{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 'Not Available', 'd': 'Not Available'}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`dict.get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
>>> d = {'key1': 'apple'}
>>> d['key1']
'apple'
>>> d.get('key2', 'Not Available')
'Not Available'
```