# How to add key value pairs to dictionary of list when key is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a disctionary of list that looks like this:

```
list = [{'sitemap': [{'path': 'http://test.com',
                      'errors': '0',
                      'contents': [{'type': 'web',
                                    'submitted': '34801',
                                    'indexed': '4656'}]}]},
        {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://example.com',
                      'errors': '0',
                      'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '2329'}]}]},
        {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://fakeurl.com', 'errors': '0'}]}]
```

'contents' key is occationally missing from some entries.

This is the ideal output I am after:

```
list = [{'sitemap': [{'path': 'http://test.com',
                      'errors': '0',
                      'contents': [{'type': 'web',
                                    'submitted': '34801',
                                    'indexed': '4656'}]}]},
        {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://example.com',
                      'errors': '0',
                      'contents': [{'type': 'web',
                                    'submitted': '2329',
                                    'indexed': 'NaN'}]}]},
        {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://fakeurl.com',
                      'errors': '0',
                      'contents': [{'type': 'NaN',
                                    'submitted': 'NaN',
                                    'indexed': 'NaN'}]}]}]
```

How can I identify if 'contents' key is missing and add a key with NaN value when it's missing?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting the missing values of dictionary with default value python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811475/setting-the-missing-values-of-dictionary-with-default-value-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over every dictionary in the `'sitemap'` to check if the `'contents'` exists. If it does not exist, create an empty list, then access each dictionary in the list and fill in the default values. If there is no dictionary, copy the entire default value and append it to the list:

```
In [_]: lst = [{'sitemap': [{'path': 'http://test.com',
   ...:           'errors': '0',
   ...:           'contents': [{'type': 'web',
   ...:                         'submitted': '34801',
   ...:                         'indexed': '4656'}]}]},
   ...:        {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://example.com',
   ...:           'errors': '0',
   ...:           'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '2329'}]}]},
   ...:        {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://fakeurl.com', 'errors': '0'}]}]
   ...:

In [_]: defaults = {'type': 'NaN', 'submitted': 'NaN', 'indexed': 'NaN'}

In [_]: for dct in lst:
   ...:     for sitemap in dct['sitemap']:
   ...:         if contents := sitemap.setdefault('contents', []):
   ...:             for content in contents:
   ...:                 for key, value in defaults.items():
   ...:                     content.setdefault(key, value)
   ...:         else:
   ...:             contents.append(defaults.copy())
   ...:
```

Output:

```
In [_]: lst
Out[_]:
[{'sitemap': [{'path': 'http://test.com',
    'errors': '0',
    'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '34801', 'indexed': '4656'}]}]},
 {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://example.com',
    'errors': '0',
    'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '2329', 'indexed': 'NaN'}]}]},
 {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://fakeurl.com',
    'errors': '0',
    'contents': [{'type': 'NaN', 'submitted': 'NaN', 'indexed': 'NaN'}]}]}]
```

If you want to reduce some indentation, you can use some tools in the stdlib:

```
In [_]: from itertools import chain
   ...: from operator import itemgetter

In [_]: for sitemap in chain.from_iterable(map(itemgetter('sitemap'), lst)):
   ...:     if contents := sitemap.setdefault('contents', []):
   ...:         for content in contents:
   ...:             for key, value in defaults.items():
   ...:                 content.setdefault(key, value)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         contents.append(defaults.copy())
   ...:
```

Comment: Thank you @Mechanic Pig. Why did you use the walrus operator in "if contents := sitemap.setdefault('contents', []):" ?

Comment: @Anchobi_codes If you want, you can split it into two lines. I use it because the judgment here is so simple that no additional parentheses are needed, which is very readable for me.

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the list. If the dictionary doesn't have the `contents` key, add it.

When `contents` exists, merge it with a list of default values for each key.

```
default_values = {'type': 'NaN', 'submitted': 'NaN', 'indexed': 'NaN'}
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for m in d['sitemap']:
        if 'contents' not in m:
            m['contents'] = [default_values.copy()]
        else:
            for i, old in enumerate(m['contents']):
                m['contents'][i] = default_values | old
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. Could you tell me what does "|" do in "m['contents'][i] = default_values | old" ?

Comment: It's the index of the list element being replaced with the merged dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can enumerate the "contents" of each sitemap and use the index to do a dictionary merge while leveraging `setdefault()`

**Given:**

```py
data = [
    {'sitemap': [{'path': 'http://test.com', 'errors': '0', 'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '34801', 'indexed': '4656'}]}]},
    {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://example.com', 'errors': '0', 'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '2329'}]}]},
    {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://fakeurl.com', 'errors': '0',}]}
]
defaults = {'type': 'NaN', 'submitted': 'NaN', 'indexed': 'NaN'}
```

**You might try:**

```py
for entry in data:
    for sitmap in entry['sitemap']:
        for index, content in enumerate(sitmap.setdefault("contents", [{}])):
            sitmap["contents"][index] = defaults.copy() | content
print(data)
```

That should give you something that formats to:

```
[
    {'sitemap': [{'path': 'http://test.com', 'errors': '0', 'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '34801', 'indexed': '4656'}]}]},
    {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://example.com', 'errors': '0', 'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '2329', 'indexed': 'NaN'}]}]},
    {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://fakeurl.com', 'errors': '0', 'contents': [{'type': 'NaN', 'submitted': 'NaN', 'indexed': 'NaN'}]}]}
]
```

Not going to win any speed contests, but I think it is fairly easy to follow.